# About solving a convex optimization problem

Tags: optimization, signal-processing, mathematical-statistics

Is there any solution for the following convex optimization problem?:
\begin{equation}
\text{argmin}_{\mathbf{X}} ||\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{Y}||_F^2 + \lambda ||\mathbf{Z} - \mathbf{FX}||_1
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{Y}$, $\mathbf{Z}$, and $\mathbf{F}$ are matrices.

$||.||_F$ represents the Frobenius norm, and $||.||_1$ is the $L_1$-norm.

Comment: Yes.  But what exactly are you asking for?  What do you mean by "is": an algorithm, an existence proof, software, something else?

Comment: Yes is there any existing proof or algorithm to solve this optimization problem? In other words, is there any closed form solution? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: So are there any suggestions from you? :)

Comment: Which matrix 1 norm are you using, the elementwise norm, the trace norm or the operator norm?

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no closed-form solution to this problem.

If a numerical solution is adequate, that is easily accomplished. Presuming that $\lambda$ is non-negative, this is a straightforward convex optimization problem, which can be formulated as (or transformed into) a convex Quadratic Programming problem (QP) or a Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP).

Here is a formulation using CVX, which will provide a numerical solution. CVX transforms the problem into a standard form which solvers can handle. I will presume $X$ is an n by n matrix variable.

```
cvx_begin
variable X(n,n)
minimize square_pos(norm(X+Y,'fro')) + lambda*norm(Z-F*X,1)
cvx_end
```